# Keycloak, First Broker Login: if no account exists ask user to link to an existing account or create new

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-services

How to configure First Broker Login to achieve the following behaviour when user sign in with Social IdP:

1. User (with on account in Keycloak) clicks on Sign in with Google
   button.
2. Keycloack doesn't automatically create a new account for
   the user but suggests to options: ***Link to existing account*** or ***Create New Account***
3. When ***Link to existing account*** user should click on sign in button of other social IdP with which user's Keycloack account was created before.
4. When ***Create New Account*** the new Keycloak account is created.

**Why do I need this?** - Different socials accounts of the same user may be registered using different emails, hence I want to avoid situation when the same user will have two accounts in my app.

So far, I disabled the Automatic user account creation by updating First Broker Login flow following the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_disabling_automatic_user_creation), but I don't know how to configure the flow to show the user ***Create New Account*** option
[image]

Can anyone explain how I can do that?

Comment: I have found pretty similar cases there https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6282